# ImportError: Could not import Theano

Tags: tensorflow, anaconda, jupyter, lasagne

Hi i'm now newbie in studying machine-learning and i want to do some sample code.

When i want to run this code

```
:
import lasagne
from lasagne import layers
from lasagne.updates import nesterov_momentum
from nolearn.lasagne import NeuralNet
from nolearn.lasagne import visualize
```

..

i got an error message like this.

```
ImportError: Could not import Theano.
```

Please make sure you install a recent enough version of Theano. Note that a
simple 'pip install theano' will usually give you a version that is too old
for Lasagne. See the installation docs for more details:

So, i want to fix this problem, i upgrade theno with this

pip install --upgrade https://github.com/theano/theano/archive/master.zip

but, i still have this problem. could anyone help me to fix this problem?

p.s. my current Lasagne version is like this 
[image]

also, my current theano version is like this

[image]

Comment: Are you sure lasagne refers to the theano with correct version?

Comment: @frankyjuang yes i found that lasagne 0.2.dev1 version should be match with theano version over 0.8 and i had with 0.9.0 version... so i don't know what the problem is...